# Python iterating RegEx that extracts text from between delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a regex function that extracts string elements from in between two predefined separators (start & end):

```
def Findy(start, end, anystring):
    result = (anystring.split(start)[1].split(end)[0])
    return result

string = "I want A and I want B and I want C and..."
Findy('want', 'and', string)
>>>'A'
```

But this only grabs the first match it finds; what I need is to get all the matches, so that;

```
Findy('want', 'and', string)
>>>['A','B','C']
```

I've tried incorporating re.findall, but I don't always know what the pattern will be that exists between my start and end delimiters, so no luck there.

How can I refactor Findy to iterate over a string and pick up all matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular expressions with look-behind and look-ahead:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "I want A and I want B and I want C and..."
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=want ).*?(?= and)', string)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

#### How it works

The regular expression divides into three parts:

- `(?<=want )`

  This matches only if preceded by the string `want`.
- `.*?`

  This matches any characters.  The trailing `?` makes this match non-greedy.  This means that it finds the shortest string that satisfies the overall regex.
- `(?= and)`

  This matches only if this point in the string is followed by `and`.

Separately and for future reference, note that `string` is the name of a standard module and it is best practice not to choose variable names that can conflict with standard modules.

#### Alternative

As AvinashRaj points out, we can also do this using a capturing group instead of the look-behind, look-ahead combination:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\bwant\s+(.*?)\s+and\b', string)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Great stuff man- elegant even! I prefer the look ahead/behind, as it's just a bit more readable. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether this code satisfies you:

```
def findy(start, end, anystr):
    res = []
    tmp = anystr.split(start)[1:]
    for e in tmp:
        res.append(e.split(end)[0].strip())
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! this did work, though I had to go with John1024's solution since it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script, redefining Findy:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re


def Findy(start, end, anystring):
    pattern = '{}(.*?){}'.format(start, end)
    return re.findall(pattern, anystring)

string = 'I want A and I want B and I want C and...'
print(Findy('want', 'and', string))
```

Output: `>>> [' A ', ' B ', ' C ']`

The pattern is as such:

1. start matches characters start
2. (.*?) . captures any character except newline, * zero or more times, ? as least as possible, () is a capture group
3. end matches characters end

**UDPATE**: if you do not want the whitespace characters you can use  `pattern = '{}\s*(\S*?)\s*{}'.format(start, end)`

```
\s matches any white space character
\S matches any non-white space character
```

Output:  `>>> ['A', 'B', 'C']`